# MIgrations erro ao carregar System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager - MIgrations

Tags: c#, code-first, entity-framework-core

Tenho um projeto WPF que contém um `app.config` contendo a consection string e tb tenho uma camada Data do tipo ClassLibrary .dot net Standard no qual deverá ser criada a a pasta do Migrations.

Quando dou um "Add-Migration Start" o sistema não está conseguindo acessar o Meu app.config e pegar a connection string para criar a Migration.

Está aparecendo esse erro:

> "Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly
>   'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' ou uma de suas
>   dependências. O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado."

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SistemaComercial" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=SistemaComercial;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />    
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

O que eu faço para resolver?

Comment: mostre como cria as _migrations_ na consola.

Comment: Add-Migration Start

Comment: NA vdd, não consigo criar nenhuma. Dá o erro que mostrei acima.

Comment: verifique a resposta que deixei em baixo

Comment: verifique qual packages.config da sua aplicação tem o System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager  e veja se você tem ele nas referencias, se não estive usando basta deletar a linha que tem ele e compilar o projeto.

Answer (score 0):

Para criar `Migrations`não basta fazer apenas "start", tem alguns passos que deve seguir, antes tem que conter no projecto o código necessário para trabalhar com `Migrations`:

```
 public class o_nome_do_seu_modeloContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<O_SEU_MODELO> nome_variavel { get; set; }
        }
```

E depois no programa principal, acessar a essas informações vindas da base de dados, instanciando a variável para a classe que criou anteriormente.

Depois disso no menu Tools>NugGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console:

**Ativa as Migrations** - a partir daqui poderá ver a pasta de Migrations criada com dois ficheiros de um Estado Inicial e outro `Configuration.cs`

- `Enable-Migrations`caso a sua solução tenha vários projectos será melhor fazer `Enable-Migrations -ProjectName 'Nome_Projecto'`

**Adicionar a Migrations** - Caso adicione outra tabela à base de dados ou pelo seguro adicione na mesma.

`Add-Migrations NOME_MIGRATION_QUE_DESEJA -ProjectName "NOME_PROJECTO"`

**Update de Migration** - Caso altere algum dados na base de dados.

`Update-Database -projectName "NOME_PROJECTO"`

Só com aquilo que tem na pergunta, está claro que faltam alguns passos, como ativar as migrations, senão tiver isso, o ficheiro de `Configuration.cs`não irá ser criado e inacessível. Aconselho-o a dar uma vista de olhos em alguns tutoriais de `Code-First`.

Comment: Enable-Migrations No EF-Core ??? ainda tem isso ???